# reinforcement learning model design - how to add upto 5

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am experimenting with reinforcement learning in python using Keras. Most of the tutorials available use OpenAI Gym library to create the environment, state, and action sets.

After practicing with many good examples written by others, I decided that I want to create my own reinforcement learning environment, state, and action sets.

This is what I think will be fun to teach the machine to do.

1. An array of integers from 1 to 4. I will call these targets.

> targets = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]

2. Additional numbers list (at random) from 1 to 4. I will call these bullets.

> bullets = [1, 2, 3, 4]

3. When I shoot a bullet to a target, the target's number will be the sum of original target num + bullet num.
4. I want to shoot a bullet (one at a time) at one of the targets to make
5. For example, given targets [1 2 3 4] and bullet 1, I want the machine to predict the correct index to shoot at.
6. In this case, it should be index 3, because 4 + 1 = 5

   > curr_state = [[1, 2, 3, 4]]
   >
   > bullet     = 1
   >
   > action     = 3 (<-- index of the curr_state)
   >
   > next_state = [[1, 2, 3, 5]]

I have been picking my brain to think of the best way to construct this into a reinforcement design. I tried some, but the model result is not very good (meaning, it most likely fails to make number 5).

Mostly because the state is a 2D: (1) targets; (2) bullet at that time. The method I employed so far is to convert the state as the following:

> State  =  5 - targets - bullet

I was wondering if anyone can think of a better way to design this model?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is more a contextual bandit problem rather than a reinforcement learning problem, because you do not look at the sequential decision making of the shooter.  One way to make it an RL problem is to have the shooter keep shooting until a value 5 is obtained.  The other problem is, how do you determine what state you are in?  I have a few ideas on how to make this, I'll post the environment later this week if no one else can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so it looks like no one is helping you out, so I just wrote a Python environment file for you as you described.  I also made it as much OpenAI style for you as possible, here is the link to it, it is in my GitHub repository.  You can copy the code or fork it.  I will explain it below:

https://github.com/RuiNian7319/Miscellaneous/blob/master/ShootingRange.py

States = [0, 1, 2, ..., 10]

Actions = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]

So the game starts at a random number between 0 - 10 (you can change this easily if you want), and the random number is your "target" you described above.  Given this target, your AI agent can fire the gun, and it shoots bullets corresponding to the numbers above.  The objective is for your bullet and the target to add up to 5.  There are negatives in case your AI agent overshoots 5, or if the target is a number above 5.

To get a positive reward, the agent has to get 5.  So if the current value is 3, and the agent shoots 2, then the agent will get a reward of 1 since he got the total value of 5, and that episode will end.

There are 3 ways for the game to end:

1) Agent gets 5

2) Agent fails to get 5 in 15 tries

3) The number is above 10.  In this case, we say the target is too far

Sometimes, you need to shoot multiple times to get 5.  So, if your agent shoots, its current bullet will be added to the state, and the agent tries again from that new state.

Example:

Current state = 2.  Agent shoots 2.  New state is 4.  And the agent starts at 4 at the next time step.  This "sequential decision making" creates a reinforcement learning environment, rather than a contextual bandit.

I hope this makes sense, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ended up trying a few different approaches. I haven't thought of your method. Let me try it out :)